# acceleration ramp "increments" for Counter AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, trigonometry

My counter goes to 100 at a constant speed.
Is there a way to ramp the speed of a counter?

Flash can use trigonometry values to effect speed,
but I don't know if that can change the timer class 
on-the-fly.

**There's a couple parts to it.** 
(a.) ramp the speed of a counter?

(b.) ramp in certain parts?
 - have a range
 - 90-100 starts ramping

**either example of trigonometry of increments would be helpful**

[alt text http://www.ashcraftband.com/myspace/videodnd/icon10.jpg](http://www.ashcraftband.com/myspace/videodnd/icon10.jpg)

**TRIG EXAMPLE I WANT TO APPLY**

```
var xVel:Number = Math.cos(radians) * speed;
var yVel:Number = Math.sin(radians) * speed;
//-------------------------------------------//
return deg * (Math.PI/180);
```

**ACCELLERATING COUNTER** "all good examples"

```
//EVERYONE HELPED "decimals corrected" 
var timer:Timer = new Timer(10);  
var count:int = 0; //start at -1 if you want the first decimal to be 0  
var fcount:int = 0; 

timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, incrementCounter);  
timer.start();  


function incrementCounter(event:TimerEvent) {  
  count++;  
  //
  fcount=int(count*count/10000);//starts out slow... then speeds up 
  //
  var whole_value:int = int(fcount / 100); //change value 
  var tenths:int = int(fcount / 10) % 10;   
  var hundredths:int = int(fcount) % 10;
```

"thanks for spending the time to help"

Comment: increments is how I would do it in C. The ammount change by multiples of depending on its greater or lesser value. If I new actionscript, I'd help

Comment: Learning ActionScript 3.0 A BEGINNER'S GUIDE Rich Shupe with Zevan Rosser. Snag this book if you can, it has some examples of what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get an simple approximation of a speeding-up effect by applying a formula to your count variable, like this:

```
var timer:Timer = new Timer(10); 
var count:int = 0; //start at -1 if you want the first decimal to be 0 
var fcount:int = 0;

timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, incrementCounter); 
timer.start(); 


function incrementCounter(event:TimerEvent) { 
  count++; 
  fcount=int(count*count/10000);//starts out slow... then speeds up 
  var whole_value:int = int(fcount/100); 
  var decimal_value:int = int(fcount/10) % 10;
  var hun_value:int = fcount % 10;
  mytext.text = whole_value + " : " + decimal_value + hun_value; 
}
```

ie: count is increasing regularly, but fcount speeds up in proportion to the square of count.

If you want a trig function, you could try `fcount=int(acos(count/10000)*10000/(2*Math.PI));` but this would only work for count<=10000.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use one of the many ActionScript tweening engines such as [TweenLite](http://blog.greensock.com/tweenlite/)?

It can do all the math for you, you just need to give it what variable to interpolate, its final value, the total duration of the interpolation, and chose between the differents easing functions.

In some cases, if you need something really custom, you can just tween a Number variable from 0 to 1, with the duration & easing function you want to use, and then define an `onUpdate` function to let you do your work with this value, which will be interpolated through time.